# Entity Framework Handle Connection Loss

Tags: frameworks, entity

Our application is using EF 5 and c#.net 4.5. Since our application is used around the world with one cenral server, we have problems with running into timeouts and losing the connection to the server.

Currently we catch the SaveChanges() method and try it again until the user cancels. What can we do for the various loadings we do in code?

Edit: I tried the proposed solution but i don't get it to work proper:

```
public class MyRetryStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex != null && ex is SqlException)
        {
            foreach (SqlError error in (ex as SqlException).Errors)
            {
                switch (error.Number)
                {
                    case 1205:
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error: Deadlock condition. Retrying...");
                        return true;

                    case -2:
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error: Timeout expired. Retrying...");
                        return true;

                    case -1:
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error: Timeout expired. Retrying...");
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ex != null && ex is EntityException)
        {
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            foreach (SqlError error in (ex as SqlException).Errors)
            {
                switch (error.Number)
                {
                    case 1205:
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error: Deadlock condition. Retrying...");
                        return true;

                    case -2:
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error: Timeout expired. Retrying...");
                        return true;

                    case -1:
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error: Timeout expired. Retrying...");
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // For all others, do not retry.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Enity Framework only throws me EntityExceptions so i added the second Code Path.

Actual Usage:

```
  RetryPolicy policy = new RetryPolicy<MyRetryStrategy>(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        policy.ExecuteAction(()=>_context.ProductStatuses.Include(x => x.Name.Translations).Load());
```

The IsTransient Method in MyRetryStrategy is never called, and also no retries are invoked. I tested it stopping the Databse before the call.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This sample got me off the ground.

http://hmadrigal.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/automatic-retries-using-the-transient-fault-handling-from-enterprise-libraries-entlib/

IService (below) is your own custom implementation.

```
private static void RetryPolityUsingCode(IUnityContainer container, IService service, OutputWriterService writer)
       {
           writer.WriteLine("Begin sample: RetryPolityUsingCode");
           // Define your retry strategy: retry 5 times, starting 1 second apart
           // and adding 2 seconds to the interval each retry.
           var retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

           // Define your retry policy using the retry strategy and the Windows Azure storage
           // transient fault detection strategy.
           var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<MyRetryStrategy >(retryStrategy);


           try
           {
               // Do some work that may result in a transient fault.
               retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(service.AMethodIDefinedInMyService);
           }
           catch (Exception exception)
           {
               // All the retries failed.
               writer.WriteLine("An Exception has been thrown:\n{0}", exception);
           }
           writer.WriteLine("End sample: RetryPolityUsingCode");
       }
```